# How to document and store cookie consents?

Tags: cookies, cookieconsent

as a web developer i am periodically exposed to the matter of cookie consents and their compliance with GDPR. I understand the question of which cookie types require a consent and, developing my own cookie consent solutions, i know how to get it technically done.

Usually i try to avoid any cookies besides technically necessary cookies. When third-party or tracking cookies become unavoidable, i ask the user's consent before they are placed and i store this consent in a first-party cookie, something like `third_party_cookie_consent = 1`.

The page about the [Cookie compliance of the GDPR](https://gdpr.eu/cookies/) says under *To comply with the regulations governing cookies under the GDPR and the ePrivacy Directive you must:* […] *Document and store consent received from users.*

But how are we exactly required to *document and store* the consent of a user? Is it enough to place a cookie on the user's machine which expresses whether consent was given? Do i have to log something to my logs and, if yes, what?

I did some research but i could not find sufficient information on this particular question of documenting a cookie consent. Thanks for any help.